# C# Can every statement be an expression?

Tags: expression, statements

Can every statement be an expression in C#? 
For example I know that a method invocation statement can be used as an expression and because of that I can do stuff like this:

`for (int i = 0; i < 10; Console.WriteLine(i++));`

But is it the case with every statement?

Edit: 
But this thing for some reason doesn't work with the while loop

`while (Console.WriteLine(1) > 0) { }`

This code gives an error. Maybe you can explain what's happening? I got a bit confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases you need an **empty statement**:

> The empty statement consists of a single semicolon. It does nothing
>   and can be used in places where a statement is required but no action
>   needs to be performed.

The reason why `for(int i = 0; i < 10; Console.WriteLine(i++));` works is because it has an empty statement `;` at the end of the block.

To make the while loop work you need to add an empty statement as well.

```
while(Console.WriteLine(1) > 0);
```